# EF Core 2.2.6 query doesn't work when trying to use NetTopologySuite

Tags: entity-framework-core, nettopologysuite

I'm trying to use NetTopologySuite with EF Core 2.2.6 to perform a geographical search.

I've successfully added a location `Point` to my model, and EF Core **can** read and write this property.

However, when I try to add this predicate to my query I see two problems:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Foo.Bar.Location.Distance(new Point(longitude, latitude) { SRID = 4326 }) <= distance);
```

1. A `NullReferenceException` exception is thrown when the query is executed.

```
   at lambda_method(Closure , TransparentIdentifier`2 )
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__17`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

2. If I look at the executed SQL in SQL Profiler, no WHERE clause is being added.

Thing I've already checked:

1. I have `UseNetTopologySuite()` in my `OnConfiguring` override.
2. I'm using `NetTopologySuite.Core` version 1.15.3, which is the appropriate version for EF Core 2.2.6.